# Asset Library permissions inherit from parent site, not subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, inheritance, asset-library, app-permissions

I have a subsite which has modified permissions. It does inherit permissions from the parent site, but I also added a new group with read-only permissions. By giving the group read on the site, they automatically got read permission to all pages and documents, exactly as expected. There is also an Asset Library added to the subsite, but for some reason this is inheriting permissions from the parent site, not the subsite, which meant a lot of error reports when users couldn't play the video files stored there.

I confirmed this by opening the Advanced Permissions page for the Asset Library, then clicking Manage Parent--I got the main site's permissions, not the subsite's. On the other hand, the Asset Library appears in the subsite's Site Contents, not the parent's.

May I assume this is a bug in SharePoint Online? Any ideas on how to connect the Library differently without changing every video URL I've already used on various pages?

Comment: Most likely problem is that the Asset Library is located in the parent, not in the subsite.  If there is only one Asset Library in the site collection, the subsites will use and upload assets to that, even it located in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Did the sub site inherit permission from the parent site?

If so, then the Asset Library will inherit permission from the sub site, in other words, it will inherit permission from the parent site.

If not, to troubleshoot the issue, you could create a new document library and check if the same issue will occur.

Comment: The issue does not occur when creating a document library.

The issue is that an Asset Library inherits differently from a document library, or any other object. If I change permissions for the subsite, they're inherited by a document library, and by all pages and Site Assets, but the Asset Library continues to inherit from the parent site, not the modified subsite permissions. This is a bug in SharePoint, in my opinion. It should be consistent.